# .htaccess redirect from specific file to an already defined rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been checking around but I can't seem to find the exact syntax to achieve what I'm trying.

I'm currently renewing a website, but as it has pretty good positions in Google I want to preserve all the links, but this time I want to use pretty url's. So, the problem I'm having is the following:

I have this bases-generales (general-rules) section and I use this to Rewrite:

```
RewriteRule     ^bases-generales/   bases.php?locale=es_LA
```

The problem I'm having is that the current (old) file is named bases.php, so I want users to be redirected to /bases-generales/ when they open bases.php directly from Google or some other link.

The rule I'm using at the moment is:

```
RewriteRule     /bases.php    http://mysite/bases-generales/ [R=301,L]
```

Now, this command does redirect, but the only problem is that the url looks like this:

```
http://mysite/bases-generales/?locale=es_LA
```

And the other problem is that it causes a Redirect Loop.

For more information this is the complete htaccess (mysite is fake of course)

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
order deny,allow

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mysite)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mysite/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite/$1/ [L,R=301]  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteBase     /

RewriteRule     ^/          index.php?locale=es_LA
RewriteRule     ^bases-generales/   bases.php?locale=es_LA
RewriteRule     ^condiciones/       condiciones.php?locale=es_LA
RewriteRule     ^programa/      programa.php?locale=es_LA
RewriteRule     ^premios/       premios.php?locale=es_LA
RewriteRule     ^ganadores/     ganadores.php?locale=es_LA
RewriteRule     ^patrocinadores/    patrocinadores.php?locale=es_LA
RewriteRule     ^galeria/       galeria.php?locale=es_LA
RewriteRule     ^contacto/      contacto.php?locale=es_LA

RewriteRule     ^bases.php      http://mysite/bases-generales/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Something strange is going on, I removed the

RewriteRule     ^bases.php      http://mysite/bases-generales/ [R=301,L]

line and now it works, but in some browsers it still adds the locale GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

concerning your first request, you have to append `?` to the new url in order to prevent Rewrite_mod from adding the querystring, so the directive will be

```
RewriteRule     ^bases.php    http://mysite/bases-generales/? [R=301,L]
```

2) you should add `L` to your rewrite rules to stop processing the url :

```
RewriteRule     ^bases-generales/   bases.php?locale=es_LA [L]
```

the htaccess will be:

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
order deny,allow

RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite/$1/ [L,R=301]  


RewriteBase     /

RewriteRule     ^bases.php    http://mysite/bases-generales/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule     ^sample2.php    http://mysite/sample2/? [R=301,L]


RewriteRule     ^bases-generales/   bases.php?locale=es_LA [L]
RewriteRule     ^sample2/    sample2.php?locale=xx [L]
```

Comment: I changed it like this and it's sending me to 404.

Comment: what is the url causing the 404 ?

Comment: Sorry I think the 404 was my fault because I had put /bases.php instead of ^bases.php but now, when I go to bases.php it does send me to /bases-generales/ but now the bases-generales section does a redirect loop. It does it even if I enter directly to /bases-generales/. I was checking de REWERITE_COND commands but I am not really sure how to use them.

Comment: Does the order in the .htaccess file affect the behavior?

Comment: have you added the L flag to your directives, also the REWERITE_COND in your code do not have any effect, they usually come before rewriterule in a many to one relationship.

Comment: I changed it like you said @amine-hajyoussef but it doesn't do anything.

Here's that part of my htaccess:

`RewriteBase   /

RewriteRule      ^bases.php          http://mysite/bases-generales/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule      ^bases-generales/       bases.php?locale=es_LA [L]`

Comment: i think it's another rule that's causing the issue, i updated my answer